# How to create a dynamic variable name ? Android Studio id name problem

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-identifiers

I am doing android and want to get id name's one by one so that I can display data on views in a correct order, so for that I saved the id's as (`selected1`, `selected2`, `selected3`, ...). Actually I want to name the selected item in MainActivity which is chosen by the user in SecondActivity and I get the name back in MainActivity using Intent.

[image: And this is the MainActivity.xml code]

But the problem is that I can't able to call id name dynamically of MainActivity's TextView like

```
int counter = 1;
// to count till which view we put the data,
// numbering is also related to name of id's you can see in image
String str_count = Integer.toString(counter);
String selected = "selected";
String id_name = selected + str_count;
// currently id_name = "selected1", I am going to increase this counter
// so next time we will get the next view
```

But it tells us to create new id with name `id_name`

[image: And this is that problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.id.*` is actually an integer value. You can get it with [`Resources#getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

```
TextView place = findViewById(
    getResources().getIdentifier("selected" + counter, "id", getPackageName())
);
```

Comment: You really solved my problem bro. Thank you :)